# Server Error in '/' Application (error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) en Azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-sql

Tengo una aplicación web ASP.NET en VB.NET subida a Azure, que se conecta con una base de datos. La base de datos también está subida a Azure, en el mismo grupo de recursos.

Pero cuando mi app trata de conectarse con la base de datos, este error aparece:

Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Cómo configuro mi app para establecer la conexión con la base de datos? Cuál es la connection string correcta? Dónde la tengo que pegar (qué archivo debo modificar, de los que subí a Azure)?

Como verán, soy una completa noob. Azure muestra todas las páginas .aspx perfectamente, y la base de datos corre todas las queries perfectamente también. Pero parece ser que no puedo establecer la conexión entre la app y la base de datos.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para cualquiera con mi mismo problema, encontré la solución.

El problema estaba en que mi código vb tenía la cadena de conexión. Entonces, era inútil cambiar esa cadena sólo en el archivo web.config.

Entonces, en mi código vb hice referencia a mi cadena de conexión, vía su atributo "name".

Después, cuando la app estaba en Azure, cambié la cadena de conexión en el archivo web.config.

Y funcionó ;)